# Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: python, windows, task, scheduler

Currently I am working in scheduling a UI automation python script using windows task scheduler. When I try to trigger the code, using the run whether user is logged in or not option checked, the automation is not running but the status is going to completed state. Please do help on this issue.

Thanks,
Swapna

Hi. Currently I am working in scheduling a UI automation python script using windows task scheduler. When I try to trigger the code, using the run whether user is logged in or not option checked, the automation is not running but the status is going to completed state. Please do help on this issue.

Thanks,
Swapna

Answer (score 0):

Double check and then triple check to make sure your password is entered correctly when you setup the Windows Track Scheduler. I've seen instances where the Task Scheduler allows you to enter your password and it takes it even if it's wrong, but if it's wrong, the task won't run. Try that and feed back here.